# Get assigned variable inside a function

Tags: php, variables

Is it possible to get the variable name to which a function is being assigned inside the function??

### Example:

```
$firstName = greet();
$John = greet();

function greet()
{
$name = /* things to get the "firstName" without the $ */;
echo "Hello $name!";
}
```

and this should print:

> Hello firstName!
>
> Hello John!

i want to do something like this, is it possible??

Comment: This is called (or along the lines of) metaprogramming and is not well handled in PHP.

Answer (score 6):

No. Not in any sane, feasible way.
There's also no sane reason to depend on this information in the first place.

Comment: (If I had to I'd do it by using `debug_backtrace` to figure out the file and line the function was called from, then fetch the file from disk and parse that line. That's a terrible terrible hack you should most certainly not use for anything. It can also easily break.)

Comment: actually, I have a code for that :p It was a curiosity matter

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY wanted to do something like this, you could write a data structure called Variable that stored the variable's name as well. But somehow I doubt you're going to have too much luck with OOP given the fact that you asked this question...